# No bibliography printed in the document

Tags: biblatex

I'm using TexMaker for my thesis, but I can't have any bibliography printed in the final document.
This is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}

...
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric,useprefix,hyperref,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliografia.bib}
...

\begin{document}

bla bla bla

\cleardoublepage
%\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Already compiled with PDFLatex + BibTex + PDFLatex (x2), but no warnings or errors displayed, and bibliography still not printed.
I put my citations in a ".bib" file, located within the same directory of the main file, is that right?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE! Why are you using BibTeX if you are declaring `backend=biber`?

Comment: You say you've run BibTeX but your document needs Biber: does your `.blg` file have some complaints?

Comment: You will have to run Biber, have a look at [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) for hints on how to make your favourite editor run Biber.

Comment: Excuse me for my english, I'm italian.

Comment: @JosephWright here is what come out from .blg file:

    This is BibTeX, Version 0.99dThe top-level auxiliary file: MAIN.aux
    I found no \citation commands---while reading file MAIN.aux
    I found no \bibdata command---while reading file MAIN.aux
    I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file MAIN.aux
    (There were 3 error messages)

Comment: @GianlucaCappanera Yup: you need to run Biber, not BibTeX, here as you've got `backend=biber` not `backend=bibtex`

Comment: Now, compiling with biber gives no warnings or errors on .blg file. However the problem has moved on some issue with the inputenc package. The biblatex guide doesn't present such an incompatibility, how could it be?

Comment: Did you clean out all "aux" files before recompiling?